# When is the http connection closed

Tags: asp.net, http

When a client send a request to IIS, there is a connection between the client and the server.
If client requests the a.aspx, the code in a.aspx as below.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Response.Write(i+"<br>");
                Response.Flush();
            }
        }
```

So it means that the connection keeps alive for 10s. is it right?【question 1】

10 seconds later, the connection will be closed?【question 2】

if I edit the code with 'while(true)', as below:

```
while(true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Response.Write(i+"<br>");
                Response.Flush();
            }
```

The connection is always alive?? or when will it be timeout?【question 3】

These are my questions.

Comment: You might find this interesting although it doesn't answer your question.  There are also some "long polling" frameworks you could google up as well that might be of interest.  http://encosia.com/easy-incremental-status-updates-for-long-requests/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relation between HTTP Keep Alive duration and TCP timeout duration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735883/relation-between-http-keep-alive-duration-and-tcp-timeout-duration)